# Does docker client support context path for registry?

Tags: docker, nexus, docker-registry, sonatype, nexus3

Sonatype Nexus documentation indicates that you can push to a docker registry without a HTTP connector as per [this](https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000761828-Docker-Repository-Reverse-Proxy-Strategies%22this%22) guide.

It states the following:

> Nexus would be listening at a non-https connector such as the default
>   8081. Docker repositories are added into Nexus as normal but would NOT be configured with any connector port values.

And the example shows:

> The reverse proxy would direct docker push commands received at
>   https://project.example.com:8086    to
>   http://locahost:8081/repository/docker-hosted-project

I'm failing to understand how `http://locahost:8081/repository/docker-
hosted-project` resolves to a registry.  I can't test this directly on the Nexus server since the docker client does not support context paths.

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Docker doesn't support context paths.  In the example, Docker is talking to a reverse proxy running on context path "/", and the reverse proxy is talking to the /repository/docker-hosted repository. In that example Docker doesn't know about anything other than the reverse proxy's context path.

Comment: Thanks. That's the same conclusion I came to when I took a closer look. So it looks like I might have to leverage url rewriting to make this work.